# Whitespace inserted when formatting cell parts via XSLT

Tags: excel, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to format portions of an Excel cell based on a variable. Each time I try I get rouge whitespace that I cannot understand. As a test I made a very simple xsl that was devoid of any real code to try to understand what Excel was doing. I'm still at a loss as to how to avoid the end result. I've removed whitespace within the XSL, since I know this can be an issue with WordML, I've tried to enclose the text via CDATA, I've tried using xsl:text and disabling escaping, and I've tried using normalize-space. In the end the result is always the same (except normalize-space which is logically one space shorter; but the base result applies).

My testing XSL, which can be run with any XML given it isn't actually doing a transform.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <Workbook>
        <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
            <Author>Developer</Author>
            <Created>2018-02-01T15:43:59Z</Created>
            <Version>16.00</Version>
        </DocumentProperties>
        <OfficeDocumentSettings xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
            <AllowPNG/>
        </OfficeDocumentSettings>
        <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
            <WindowHeight>12345</WindowHeight>
            <WindowWidth>25200</WindowWidth>
            <WindowTopX>0</WindowTopX>
            <WindowTopY>0</WindowTopY>
            <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
            <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
        </ExcelWorkbook>
        <Styles>
            <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
                <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
                <Borders/>
                <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"/>
                <Interior/>
                <NumberFormat/>
                <Protection/>
            </Style>
        </Styles>
        <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
            <Table>
                <Row>
                    <Cell>
                        <Data ss:Type="String">1 TEST</Data>
                    </Cell>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Cell>
                        <ss:Data ss:Type="String" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
                            <Font html:Color="#000000"><![CDATA[2 ]]></Font>
                            <B>
                                <Font html:Color="#000000"><![CDATA[TEST]]></Font>
                            </B>
                        </ss:Data>
                    </Cell>
                </Row>
                <Row ss:Height="18.75"><Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><Font html:Color="#000000">3 </Font><Font html:Size="14" html:Color="#000000">TEST</Font></ss:Data></Cell></Row>
                <Row ss:Height="18.75">
                    <Cell>
                        <ss:Data ss:Type="String" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
                            <Font html:Color="#000000"><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">4 </xsl:text></Font>
                            <B>
                                <Font html:Size="14" html:Color="#000000"><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">TEST</xsl:text></Font>
                            </B>
                        </ss:Data>
                    </Cell>
                </Row>
                <Row ss:Height="18.75">
                    <Cell>
                        <ss:Data ss:Type="String" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
                            <Font html:Color="#000000"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space('5 ')"/></Font>
                            <Font html:Size="14" html:Color="#000000"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space('TEST')"/></Font>
                        </ss:Data>
                    </Cell>
                </Row>
                <Row ss:Height="18.75">
                    <Cell>
                        <ss:Data ss:Type="String" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
                            <Font html:Color="#000000">6 </Font>
                            <B>
                                <Font html:Size="14" html:Color="#000000">TEST</Font>
                            </B>
                        </ss:Data>
                    </Cell>
                </Row>

            </Table>
            <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
                <PageSetup>
                    <Header x:Margin="0.3"/>
                    <Footer x:Margin="0.3"/>
                    <PageMargins x:Bottom="0.75" x:Left="0.7" x:Right="0.7" x:Top="0.75"/>
                </PageSetup>
                <Print>
                    <ValidPrinterInfo/>
                    <HorizontalResolution>600</HorizontalResolution>
                    <VerticalResolution>600</VerticalResolution>
                </Print>
                <Selected/>
                <Panes>
                    <Pane>
                        <Number>3</Number>
                        <ActiveCol>1</ActiveCol>
                    </Pane>
                </Panes>
                <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>
                <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>
            </WorksheetOptions>
        </Worksheet>
    </Workbook>
</xsl:template>
```

This results in
 [image: Test Result]

I would expect no whitespacing before any of the elements in rows 2 through 6. what really seems strange is that when looked at via Visual Studio Code there is no white space in the file. This spacing appears to be coming via something within the Font and B, but the structure is identical to what you would get when viewing a file created directly in Excel without all the whitespace.

Comment: Is that in any way an XSLT problem? Then we would need to see a minimal but complete stylesheet, including any namespace declarations and of course any `xsl:output` elements. But if the XML you create with XSLT is not displayed as wanted with Excel then it rather seems a problem to understand the XML format Excel uses.

Comment: I agree with Martin, it's not a problem with your XSLT, it's something you are not understanding about the semantics of the Excel XML vocabulary. All this stuff with CDATA and disable-output-escaping is clutching at straws: if the whitespace isn't present in the XML result, then you're looking for a solution in the wrong place. (disable-output-escaping, by the way, has no effect unless there are characters that need escaping, such as `<` and `&`)

Comment: Then please tell me what I'm not understanding about the semantics of Excel XML vocabulary. I used CDATA and disable-output-escaping because if I didn't someone would likely suggest that. I was fully aware it is of limited use in this. I listed Excel in the tags because I felt it might be something in Excel, but it only appears when the sheet is created via SpreadsheetML, therefore logic indicates it is somewhere in that transformation.

Comment: So what happens if you change `indent="yes"` in `xsl:output` to `indent="no"`? Does Excel still show that white space you don't want?

Comment: That was it. The indent="no" removes the whitespace. Something I didn't even think to try. I feel a fool now.